# If a method is synchronized, do the called methods also have to be synchronized?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

If a method is synchronized, do the called methods also have to be synchronized? What is correct in the following example?

```
// Only parent method synchronized 
public synchronized void parentMethod() {
    childMethod1();
}

public void childMethod1() {
    childMethod2();
}

public void childMethod2() {
    
}



// All methods synchronized 
public synchronized void parentMethod() {
    childMethod1();
}

public synchronized void childMethod1() {
    childMethod2();
}

public synchronized void childMethod2() {
    
}
```

Comment: Depends on your usecase. would childMethod1 and childMethod2 only be called from parentMethod or can they also be called from other callers and need to be synchronized when called there? After all, the methods are public.

Comment: The answer might  differ if childmethod was private. Is it public by design?

Comment: Any method that protects a non-thread-safe resource needs to be synchronized or use some other form of sequentialization *unless* it can be shown that this is already accomplished upstream. Analysis is required. There is no single answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a method is synchronized, do the called methods also have to be synchronized?

No.

There is no general reason that you need to call a `synchronized` method from another `synchronized` method.

Assuming that the methods are synchronizing on the same object then all patterns are valid, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

- calling a `synchronized` method from a `synchronized` method
- calling a `synchronized` method from a plain method
- calling a plain method from a `synchronized` method
- calling a plain method from a plain method

In all but the last case, the called method will hold the lock on the target object.

(In the first case, it appears as if the thread is going to the same object twice.  In fact, Java primitive locks are re-entrant ... so this is not a problem.)

---

If the method calls were on *different* target objects, it gets a bit more complicated.  Now you have to consider whether your application requires both objects to be locked.  Also you need to consider the possibility of deadlocks.  (If two threads attempt to simultaneously acquire the same two primitive locks, but in a different order, you will get a deadlock.)

---

It is not actually possible to give hard rules about which methods *need* to be synchronized<sup>1</sup>.  It depends on what the methods do, and whether you are using primitive lock mutexes or some other mechanism (`Lock`, `volatile`, immutable types, etc) to synchronize and/or ensure memory visibility.  And even for primitive lock mutexes, you can either use `synchronized` methods of `synchronized` blocks to achieve the same thing.

---

<sup>1 - Note that the question doesn't ask this anyway!</sup>

Comment: Just a minor comment. As mentioned in this answer, it's not required to declare the second method as synchronized, but if you are updating a shared resource in it, you either ensure all the methods calling that method are synchronized or you have to synchronize that method as well.

Comment: It is a lot more complicated than that.  Too complicated for this question ... as well as being beyond the scope of the question.